# Entity framework problem: How to handle errored column

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I'm using ado.net entity data model. When update entity object, this error shown `"String or binary data would be truncated"` or `"SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."`. I know why this error shown.

How to handle this error created on which column ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an uninitialized `DateTime` property on your object. The default value, which is in the year 0, cannot be stored in SQL Server's weirdly limited `DATETIME` columns. Set the property to a reasonable value or make it nullable in your DB.

Comment: I know error reason. I have too many `datetime` and `nvarchar` column. I need to handle which column data inserted wrong. If i can get it, i'm prompt message to users

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Craig you could set both - the db-field and the variable - to nullable. Might be a bit more performant.

Comment: Go ahead and ask a db-admin how micro this is!